# PHP foreach loop - need different value from text shown

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a simple `foreach` loop as follows:

```
foreach ($d_38 as $value) {
    echo "
        <option value='".$value."'";
            if ($results["q".$i]==$value) echo 'selected="selected"';     
    echo">".$value."</option>
";
}
```

I currently have the the information stored in an array called `$d_38` this information is placed into the `options` of the drop down during the `foreach` loop.

That all works fine.  However, I have a different language stored in `$d_38_t` that I want to show when the text of the option is shown, in the code above this is the **third** `$value` variable.  So basically, the user sees the options in one language but the data is always stored in `English` in this case.

I've no idea how to put those two arrays together so I can use them in the `foreach` loop - can anyone offer any guidance please?

Comment: I feel like this is missing [tag:php], no? -- And, FWIW, this isn't a jQuery question at all. **EDIT** Much better.

Comment: I'm suitably embarrassed...been entrenched with jQuery today...hence it's on my brain...thanks Brad!

Comment: Probably much easier to use a regular for loop to iterate over one array and inside access data from both arrays, provided they are sorted the same way.

Comment: `$d_38` and `$d_38_t` has the same keys?

Comment: Yep, same keys panther.

Comment: @Homer_J: May want to look at `PHP_EOL` as well and tidy up that code. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `key` to `foreach` and use it in as the key of `$d_38_t`.

```
foreach ($d_38 as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value='" . $value . "'";
        if ($results["q".$i] == $value) echo 'selected="selected"';    
    echo ">" . $d_38_t[$key] . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: Probably better to stick with foreach. Keys may not be numeric, and foreach will retain this relationship.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the keys **are numeric** and align between `$d_38` and `$d_38_t`, you can use a `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($d_38); $i++)
{
    // ...snip...
    echo ">" . $d_38_t[$i] . "</option>";
}
```

*Going to keep it, but do be warned: this only works with numeric keys. @panther has the **correct** answer. ;-)*